# How do optical prisms perform a Fourier-transform

Tags: optics, fourier-transform, frequency

I think I have a lackluster understanding of the time-frequency-uncertainty.

I know that $\Delta f \cdot \Delta t \ge \frac{1}{2}$ where $\Delta f$ and $\Delta t$ are the uncertainty in frequency and time. I am also familiar with the Fourier-transform and that longer signals result in a sharper spectrum.

What I can't wrap my head around are optical prisms:
They produce a rainbow by refracting light which I can see. The intensity of the light at a specific angle should then corresponds to Fourier-transform for that frequency. I imagine they are like a mechanical Fourier-Transform.

But what is their $\Delta t$? And how sharp is the spectrum they produce? Does the spectrum become sharper the longer the light shines trough it?

Comment: Ultrafast (fs) laser pulses have fairly high bandwidths. High enough that we used to us a diffraction grating to disperse it, spatially limit it mechanically, then a grating to reassemble the pulse. A mechanical Fourier transform filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this paper may answer your question, although I couldn't find the whole paper available anywhere, unless you have privileges to download from the American Journal of Physics: [Monochromators as light stretchers](https://www.deepdyve.com/lp/american-association-of-physics-teachers/monochromators-as-light-stretchers-sKSE8kqclm). It showed that indeed the prism does hold on to light for a time period that is commensurate with the uncertainty relation that you wrote. Ditto for a diffraction grating.